Python multiplatform script
Good morning.
I have a question about the multi-platform nature of a script written in Python.
Assumptions:
1.The script is to be written for OT. Which involves running it, e.g. from a pendrive by connecting it to a computer.
2.The script can be run on systems:
windows xp 32bit SP 2
windows xp 32bit SP 3
windows xp 64bit SP 2
windows xp 64bit SP 3
windows 7 32bit
windows 7 64bit
windows 8 32bit
windows 8 36bit
windows 10 32bit
windows 10 64bit
windows 11 32bit
windows 11 64bit
3.Python is not installed.
Problems I encountered.
*I installed several operating systems on virtualbox with the highest supported versions of python and:

the code of modules used in the script may not be understandable for Python in a lower version (Windows XP 32bit Python 3.4.4 and the module may have "Type Hints", etc.)
-All popular pyTOexe compilers fail to compile properly on 32Bit, especially on Windows XP 32Bit.

What's this for? E.g. for inventory. I wrote a script that extracts information within 2 seconds:
Example:
Network name IP SubnetMask DNS1 DNS2 Gateway DHCP
5 Nein Nein 2.2.2.2 Nein Nein Ja
networt-test-enabled 10.1.1.155 255.0.0.0 10.1.1.28 10.1.1.30 Nein Nein
Ethernet 2 192.168.56.1 255.255.255.0 Nein Nein Nein Nein
Ethernet 172.17.4.155 255.255.0.0 172.17.1.28 172.17.1.30 172.17.1.6 Nein
host_name: X001111DE
OS: MicrosoftWindows10Pro 10.0.19045N
Bluetooth: Nein
7zip: ME
Adobe: ME
TeamViewer Nein
.NET: 4.8.09037
The question is whether there is a way to convert it to exe or otherwise to run the code written on the above-mentioned systems.
